# How to Verify link using dataprovider

Tags: selenium, selenium2, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify hyperlink which in under the red border using data provider method. print them

1) User can click on hyperlink
2) Using data provider print the text into the console.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verify hyperlink using dataprovider](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18955/verify-hyperlink-using-dataprovider)